# Why do String literals conform to Scala Singleton

Tags: scala

Wisely or not, I'm writing a method that I'd like to accept only Scala singletons, i.e. objects implemented via "object" rather than constructed instances of a class or trait. It should accept Scala singletons of any type, so "MySingleton.type" won't do.

I came upon the very strange construct "scala.Singleton", which is not documented in the api docs, but seems to do the trick:

```
scala> def check( obj : Singleton ) = obj
check: (obj: Singleton)Singleton

scala> check( Predef )
res0: Singleton = scala.Predef$@4d3e9963

scala> check ( new java.lang.Object() )
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.Object
 required: Singleton
              check ( new java.lang.Object() )

scala> check( Map )
res3: Singleton = scala.collection.immutable.Map$@6808aa2d

scala> check( Map.empty[Any,Any] )
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any]
 required: Singleton
              check( Map.empty[Any,Any] )
```

However, rather inexplicably (to me), String literals are accepted as Singletons while explicitly constructed Strings are not:

```
scala> check( "foo" )
res7: Singleton = foo

scala> check( new String("foo") )
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String
 required: Singleton
              check( new String("foo") )
```

Why do String literals conform to Singleton? Am I misunderstanding what the Singleton type is supposed to specify?

Comment: I'm not positive but I believe it's because the compiler interns them by default.

Comment: First time I hear of `scala.Singleton`, and it is not in the docs. I wouldn't bet on it making any particular promises. In fact, I'm not sure there is any hard criterion by which you can distinguish singleton objects from classes. Can you elaborate what you try to achieve by identifying them?

Comment: (my motivation is fairly trivial: i want to be able to export fully qualified names of the Java forwarding classes, so i can use singleton methods as statics via Java reflection. i don't like relying on mangled/dollar-signed names, as they might change. so, i write a utility that un-dollarsigns singleton class names to the names Scala makes available to Java. if the mangling changes, i just need to update my method. the method is only applicable to Scala singletons, so if the type system is capable of enforcing it, i'd like it to require a singleton before getting & demangling the classname.)

Comment: BTW, Scala 2.10 will offer a reflection API that will help out here.

Comment: You might be interested to know that `check(1)` also works.  It seems all of the primitive values are considered singletons.  `check(Double.NegativeInfinity)` also works.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, what is a singleton type? If you take the view that a type is a set of values, a singleton type is a set with exactly one element.

Most commonly, a top level object can inhabit such a set.

```
scala> object X
defined module X

scala> X: X.type
res41: X.type = X$@131d1cb

scala> res41: Singleton
res42: Singleton = X$@131d1cb
```

More generally, and *stable* value can form a singleton type.

```
scala> object X { val y: String = "boo" }
defined module X

scala> X.y: X.y.type
res44: X.y.type = boo

scala> res44: Singleton
res45: Singleton = boo
```

If `y` is a `def` or a `var`, it no longer qualifies, as the value might not be the same over time, so the compiler can't guarantee that the singleton type classifies one-and-only-one value.

```
scala> object X { def y: String = "boo" }
defined module X

scala> X.y: X.y.type
<console>:12: error: stable identifier required, but X.y found.
              X.y: X.y.type
                     ^

scala> object X { var y: String = "boo" }
defined module X

scala> X.y: X.y.type
<console>:12: error: stable identifier required, but X.y found.
              X.y: X.y.type
                     ^
```

One more limitation: `AnyVal`s can't form singleton types, because the language specification specifically restricts them to `AnyRef`.

Paul Phillips has been curating a [branch](https://github.com/paulp/scala/commit/824ce5e) which allows you to express a singleton type for literals.

```
val xs: Stream[0.type](0)
val ys: Stream[0.type](0, 1) // does not compile
val x = xs.head // inferred type is 0.type, we statically know that this can only be 0!
```

Comment: interesting, thanks. i really like the idea of "<literal>.type" types. but i still don't get the purpose of scala.Singleton. as pst points out above, a type should describe a durable characteristic of a referent, not just something historical. it's hard to see the point of a type guaranteeing that something was, at some moment in time, the single element of a set referred to by a reference. after all, it's trivial to "cast" any var to this by assigning to val in a transient scope. and why should a def fail if the same fcn as a val ("val f = (a : Int) => 2 * a") conforms?

Comment: What would be the 'user-side' purpose of `Singleton`; is there any useful application involving this 'type'?

Comment: "after all, it's trivial to "cast" any var to this by assigning to val in a transient scope". A "snapshot" of the current value of var is stable; this doesn't subvert the notion of stability.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, every immutable reference qualifies as a singleton in this context, not just Strings. You can, for instance, `invoke check(5)`, or `val foo = List(1,2,3); check(foo)`. `var bar = List(1,2,3); check(bar)` will not work, however.

Judging by this behavior, I'd assume that a reference is considered a Singleton if the compiler can determine that it will never change (or is 'final' in this context).

Comment: I don't get the bit about the `List` it seems like the *type* of the expression should be checked, not the variable/field that it evaluates from .. yet the former does pass while the latter fails. Is there other compiler magic wrt Singleton and type-checking? Where are the rules specified?

Comment: Yes, true and interesting (and, as pst suggests a really odd kind of type system behavior). Any val seems to conform (including vals referencing mutable types), while all vars fail (including vars initiated to immutable literals). Literals that map to java primitives and Strings seem to conform (including null, true/false, and Class literals), more complex Scala-y literals (e.g. symbols, function, XML literals) don't. It looks like whatever the Singleton type checks, it's not really what I'm after. I do wish I understood it better, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest clue is comes from chapter 3 in the Scala Reference, section 3.2.1:

> A singleton type is of the form p.type,where p is a path pointing to a
>   value expected to conform (§6.1) to scala.AnyRef. The type denotes the
>   set of values consisting of null and the value denoted by p.
>
> A stable type is either a singleton type **or a type which is declared
>   to be a subtype of trait scala.Singleton.**

The concept of stable types is important, and the trait makes it possible to declare things to be stable that would not otherwise be considered so.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to read the spec to understand what "stability" means in this context and why it is important. Again, I find it kind of baffling, given the observable behavior of scala.Singleton.