# Ostensible inconsistencies in singleton types

Tags: scala, types, programming-languages, type-systems, singleton-type

I have a couple of questions about singleton types, but since they're both very closely related, I am posting them under the same thread.

Q1. Why does #1 does not compile but #2 does?

```
def id(x: Any): x.type = x      // #1
def id(x: AnyRef): x.type = x   // #2
```

Q2. The type is correctly inferred in case of `String` but not in case of other reference types I tried. Why is that so?

```
scala> id("hello")
res3: String = hello

scala> id(BigInt(9))
res4: AnyRef = 9

scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> id(new Foo)
res5: AnyRef = Foo@7c5c5601
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Singleton types can only refer to `AnyRef` descendants. See [Why do String literals conform to Scala Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594828/why-do-string-literals-conform-to-scala-singleton/11598340#11598340) for more details.

The argument the application `id(BigInt(9))` can't be referred to via a stable path, so consequently doesn't have an interesting singleton type.

```
scala> id(new {})
res4: AnyRef = $anon$1@7440d1b0

scala> var o = new {}; id(o)
o: Object = $anon$1@68207d99
res5: AnyRef = $anon$1@68207d99

scala> def o = new {}; id(o)
o: Object
res6: AnyRef = $anon$1@2d76343e

scala> val o = new {}; id(o) // Third time's the charm!
o: Object = $anon$1@3806846c
res7: o.type = $anon$1@3806846c
```

Comment: Thanks for the `val`/`var`/`def` explanation. Can you please expand on "can't be referred to via a stable path" bit?

Comment: It's the same rule that governs what you can import. `val x = new {}; import x._` is allowed, `import (new {})._` is not.

Answer (score -1):

I get error on #2 too (using Scala 2.9.1.final):

```
error: illegal dependent method type
  def id(x: AnyRef): x.type = x;          ^
one error found
```

I believe the correct solution is to use make `id` polymorphic using a type parameter:

```
def id[T <: Any](x: T): T = x;
```

Comment: Run it with `-Ydependent-method-types` flag, or use some Scala 2.10 milestone release.