# The place of Scala singletons in the type hierarchy

Tags: scala

Do given an singleton object defined in Scala...

```
object Foo;
```

There is a type, Foo.type, which represents the type to which that object uniquely conforms. Cool!

But what else do I know about that type. Anything? I can tell that Foo.type is a subtype of AnyRef. Cool!

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
val fooTypeTypeTag = implicitly[TypeTag[Foo.type]]
val anyRefTypeTag = implicitly[TypeTag[AnyRef]]
fooTypeTypeTag.tpe <:< anyRefTypeTag.tpe            // true
fooTypeTypeTag.tpe =:= anyRefTypeTag.tpe            // false
```

But is there anyway to know whether Foo.type is a direct descendent of AnyRef? Is there, maybe, some common type to which all singleton objects (things defined via "object XXX") conform? It [isn't scala.Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594828/why-do-string-literals-conform-to-scala-singleton), but it seems natural that all the types Foo.type, Bar.type, etc. should express some common trait. Does such a thing exist?

After having done the work to find the TypeTag for Foo.type, is there some means of employing Scala reflection to explore Foo.type's supertypes and traits? Obviously such a thing couldn't be exhaustive, there'd be a combinatorial explosion of potential duck types for example, but still it seems odd not to be able to climb a declared or built-in inheritance hierarchy by reflection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no common trait between the singletons, but they are not necessarily direct descendants from `AnyRef`, since an `object` can extend a `class` or `trait`.